# creating a table with hive based on a parquet file

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, schema, parquet

i have a parquet file stored in hdfs called small in path:

> /user/s/file.parquet

and want to create a table in hive containing it's content.

the schema of the file is very complected and i want hive to automatically import the schema from the file.

i want to do something like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tableName
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 'file/path'
```

is this possible?

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible to create external table on a single file in Hive, just for directories. If `/user/s/file.parquet` is the only file in the directory you can indicate location as `/user/s/` and Hive will catch up your file.

Comment: thank you, but i still need to specify the table schema when doing this.
I dont want to write in my CREATE TABLE statement 
 (a int, b string, c float) <= THIS PART

Comment: Well, currently it's not possible, here are issues to track the feature progress: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10593 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-8950